# Шифр Цезаря на C++ . Помогите с реализацией программы новичку

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, код не работает, выдает вот такую ошибку.
[i] выражение должно иметь тип указателя на объект, но имеет тип "int"
[i] на все эти i ругается. Я новичок, прям вообще с нуля учусь всего месяц, не ругайтесь если полную чушь кодирую.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char p;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    while (p != '3')
    {
        cout << "\nВас приветствует программа \"Шифр Цезаря 1.0\"\n\n";
        cout << "Выберите действие :" << endl;
        cout << "1.Шифрование \n" <<
                "2.Дешифрование \n" <<
                "3.Выход \n\n";
        cin >> p;

        switch (p)
        {
        case '1':
        {
            
            int simvol;
            int shift;

            cout << "\"Введите количество символов слова\"-" << endl;
            cin >> simvol;
            cout << "\"Введите сдвиг, на который хотите изменить слово\"-" << endl;
            cin >> shift;
            cout << "\"Введите слово латинскими буквами\"-" << endl;
            char* stroka = new char[simvol];
            for (int i = 0; i < simvol; ++i)
            {
                cin >> stroka[i];
            }
            if (stroka)
            {
                char newstroka;
                for (int i = 0; stroka[i] != '\0'; ++i)
                {
                    newstroka = stroka[i];
                    if (newstroka >= 'a' && newstroka <= 'z')
                    {
                        newstroka = newstroka - shift;
                        if (newstroka < 'a')
                        {
                            newstroka = newstroka + 'z' - 'a' + 1;
                        }
                        stroka[i] = newstroka;
                    }
                    else if (newstroka >= 'A' && newstroka <= 'Z')
                    {
                        newstroka = newstroka - shift;
                        if (newstroka < 'A')
                        {
                            newstroka = newstroka + 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
                        }
                        stroka[i] = newstroka;
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        }
        case '2':
        {
            int stroka;
            char simvol;
            char shift;
            cout << "\"Ведите слово латинскими буквами\"-" << endl;
            cin >> stroka;
            cout << "\"Введите количество символов слова\"-" << endl;
            cin >> simvol;
            break;
        }
        case '3':
        {
            cout << "Выход из программы \"Шифр Цезаря 1.0\"" << endl;
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "Ошибка!Попробуйте ввести действие из меню." << endl;
        }

        break;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот эта строка ```char* stroka = new char[stroka];``` Вам самому не кажется странной?

Comment: Если честно, мне пока все кажется странным. Поэтому и спрашиваю) Я что то делаю, но пока до конца не понимаю, что именно.

Comment: Хорошо. Сравните ту строку, что я привел, с той что стоит у Вас в коде выше: ```int stroka;``` Ни на какие мысли не наводит?

Comment: char* stroka = new char[simvol];
   for (int i = 0; i < simvol; ++i)
   {
    cin >> stroka[i];
   }

Comment: Уже лучше, но еще не все. Вы объявляете две переменных разного типа ```int``` и ```char*```, но с одинаковым именем ```stroka```,  причем пытаетесь читать с клавиатуры ввод строки в переменную типа ``int```

Comment: К слову, с типами переменных у Вас полная каша. Вы вводите количество символов, то есть целочисленный  параметр,  в переменную ```simvol```, имеющую , почему-то , тип ```char```. То же самое с переменной ```shift```. Послушайте совета, возьмите любую хорошую книжку по языку, и постарайтесь разобраться, как и для чего какие типы данных применять.

Comment: Исправил, теперь второй вопрос.

Comment: Вас приветствует программа "Шифр Цезаря 1.0"

Выберите действие :
1.Шифрование
2.Дешифрование
3.Выход

1
"Введите количество символов слова"-
6
"Введите сдвиг, на который хотите изменить слово"-
4
"Введите слово латинскими буквами"-
privet
lnerapээээЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭ
Почему в конце выводит посторонние символы?

Comment: Новый вопрос, по правилам сайта, надо оформлять отдельно.

Comment: Хорошо. Сейчас сделаю.

Comment: Видимо потому что в конце пропущен null, служащий признаком окончания строки

Comment: в конце case '1'?

Comment: В конце строки... И место под него не забудьте выделить.

Comment: Все равно не понял(

Comment: for (int i = 0; stroka[i] != '\0'; ++i) поменяете на for (int i = 0; simvol < i; i++). ++i, говорит нам о том, что сначала происходит инкремент в цикле. То есть, вы начинаете свой цикл с 1 и кончаете размерностью вашего массива. У вас обязательно произойдет выход за его границы из-за этого. Если еще проще. Массив размерностью 5. Вы считываете символы 1,2,3,4,5. 5 символа не существует (массив начинается с 0).

Comment: Все равно выводит в конце слова всякий мусор

Comment: @RottenRat `for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)` и `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)` выполняют одинаковую работу. "бегут" по одним и тем же `i`: `[0; n)`. неважно что вы напишете в последнем разделе цикла `for`: `i++` или `++i`

Comment: @n1tr0xs проверил, спасибо, действительно так, думал инкремент раньше срабатывает